# Confusion about paramerters in Keras LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(1, 30)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=15, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Can someone tell me what the `5` in `LSTM(5,...)` and the `1` in `Dense(1)` do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The "5" in LSTM stands for "5" LSTM units
- The "1" in Dense stands for "1" neuron in that layer

Link to the docs 
[LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm)
[Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense)

Answer (score 1):

- The "5" in [LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) is the dimensionality of the output space, which means:

  - The input arrays have the shape defined in `input_shape=(1, 30)`;
  - The output arrays have the shape (*, 5).
- The "1" in [Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense) is the dimensionality of the output space too, which means:

  - The input arrays have the shape of the output in LSTM layer (*, 5);
  - The output arrays have the shape (*, 1).

Answer (score 0):

Well you actually have it all in Keras' documentation

[image: LSTM]
[image: Dense]

https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

Their documentation is really intuitive and helpful, just use it.